# Trying to map a Java ADAL acquireToken() method to the ruby ADAL implementation

Tags: adal

The ADAL Java implementation has the following method:

```java
public Future<AuthenticationResult> acquireToken(final String resource,
        final AsymmetricKeyCredential credential,
        final AuthenticationCallback callback)
```

I am trying to map it onto the appropriate ADAL Ruby implementation method. The method would acquire a token based on a certificate for a Service Principal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be [`acquire_token_for_client(resource, client_cred)`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby/blob/master/lib/adal/authentication_context.rb), where `client_cred` is any of `ClientCredential`, `ClientAssertion`, `ClientAssertionCertificate`. Sounds like you would use the [`ClientAssertionCertificate`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby/blob/master/lib/adal/client_assertion_certificate.rb) option.